# MySQL import gets slower over time – improvements possible?

Tags: mysql, database, performance, database-performance

I have a huge mysqldump file (~700GB) that I want to restore on a different server. For the first GBs, the import is quite fast with some MB/s, but after some GB of data, the speed drops to something between 50kb/s to 200kb/s.

Params for the mysqldump were `--skip-comments --no-create-info --no-autocommit --quick --extended-insert --insert-ignore --compress`, so some speed improvements were done already.

Import is done by `pv /file.sql | mysql -u USER DB`

I also run mysqltuner and improved some of the settings there.

I’m wondering: Is it common for a mysqldump this large to have slow speeds after some time? Or is there anything that can be improved further?

Comment: Yes it is common that restoring a mysqldump file takes a long time. Depending on your server, 700GB could take many hours or even days. Also, mysqltuner is garbage, frequently gives wrong advice, and I would recommend you delete it.

Comment: Additional DB information request, please. 
RAM size, # cores, any SSD or NVME devices on MySQL Host server? 
Post TEXT data on justpaste.it and share the links. 
From your SSH login root, Text results of: 
A) SELECT COUNT(*) FROM information_schema.tables;
B) SHOW GLOBAL STATUS;    after minimum 24 hours UPTIME
C) SHOW GLOBAL VARIABLES; 
D) SHOW FULL PROCESSLIST; 
E) STATUS;  not SHOW STATUS, just STATUS;
G) SHOW ENGINE INNODB STATUS; 
for server workload tuning analysis to provide suggestions. 
MySQLTuner does include some valuable information, that saves hours of looking.

Comment: Thanks!
A&B:
https://justpaste.it/2dpio
C: https://justpaste.it/678m1
D: https://justpaste.it/6die5
E: Gave error message
F: https://justpaste.it/43prj

Comment: 8GB RAM, 4 Cores, HDD, so I don’t expect very high speeds, but the drops are what I’m wondering about

Comment: @Tibor Thanks for posting additional DB information.  See Answer with 4 Suggestions to improve data loading rate per second.

Answer (score 2):

When importing large volumes of data, the following should be disabled.

1. disable triggers
2. disable indexes
3. disable constraints or checks
4. disable foreign-keys

Because every time during an insert, the DB checks the relationships of the inserted record in other tables. And as tables get bigger and bigger, this process starts to slow down. Each time during an insert, the DB also performs an additional insert into the index of that table or runs insert triggers.

Also, because the transaction in MySQL is very weak, it is necessary to work so that commit does not work every time after insert, the commit command can be used, for example, once after every 10000 record inserts.

Comment: Look inside the dump file -- it may already be turning off indexes and/or foreign keys, etc.

Comment: Thanks so much! Tried that, but the speed would drop nevertheless

Answer (score 2):

Rate Per Second = RPS

Suggestions to consider for your my.cnf [mysqld] section

```
innodb_log_file_size=1G  # from 50M to support almost 1 Hr before rotation
innodb_log_buffer_size=500M  # from 16M to support about 30 min before write log data
innodb_buffer_pool_size=4G  # from 128M to better support your data loading process
innodb_change_buffer_max_size=50  # to improve innodb_data_writes RPS of 369
```

Please view profile for contact info.  Many more Global Variables could be significantly improved.

After a couple days of similar processing, let us know if better/worse for performance, please.

Comment: @Tibor         Any feedback on system after suggestions applied?  Better or worse?